# c# Encoding conversion?

Tags: .net, html, encoding

I have a string which looks like:

```
 &#xC0; l&#x27;int&#xE9;rieur
```

But it needs to be:

```
 À l'intérieur
```

I tried changing the conversion. I know it's read as ASCII encoding. So I tried using the code:

```
      ASCIIEncoding ASCII  = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
      Byte[] BytesMessage = ASCII.GetBytes(Title);
      Title = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(BytesMessage);
```

I tried switching between the different encodings but it didn't help much.
Is there a way to fix this?

Thx!

Comment: What's the difference between these two strings?

Comment: There is nothing different between those two strings...

Comment: I've editted, markdown+html were giving away the answer

Comment: Is that initial string correct now? It looks like there's spaces between the ampersands and the # characters that shouldn't be there if this is HTML encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To transcode HTML encoded strings like this use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Title)`. You'll need to reference `System.Web` if this is not a Web application.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I needed. For others, to be exact. It's HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Title).

Answer (score 6):

Well, this is actually not a *character* encoding (such as ASCII or UTF-8) but rather a higher-level protocol defining escape sequences for arbitrary characters—in this case SGML which serves as the basis for HTML and XML.

You can use the [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) method of the [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) class to decode it:

```
PS> Add-Type -AssemblyName system.web
PS> [web.httputility]::HtmlDecode("&#xC0; l&#x27;int&#xE9;rieur")
À l'intérieur
```

However, this class resides in the System.Web namespace so it's probably not immediately available in a non-ASP.NET project.

Comment: Whoo-hoo! +1 for the Powershell example.

Comment: It's the easiest way to test something in .NET without actually firing up Visual Studio, opening one of the dozens ConsoleProject1 solutions, etc. :-)